# How can I compile all .cpp files except one using g++?

Tags: bash, g++

To compile all C++ files in my source directory I run

```
g++ -std=c++17 ../src/*.cpp -o ../out/a.out
```

How can I compile all `cpp` files in a given directory except for `main.cpp`?

Comment: We could glob into an array (`files=(../src/*.cpp)`) and then [remove an element from a Bash array](/q/16860877)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
g++ -std=c++17 ../src/!(main).cpp -o ../out/a.out
```

ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching

Comment: I *knew* there was an `extglob` solution!  Just couldn't quite remember the syntax.  Thanks!

Comment: What exactly does `shopt -s extglob` do?

Comment: It enables the *extended patterns* that extend plain glob wildcards into something closer to regular expressions. Read that section of the manual that I linked for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in $(find /path/to/files -name "*.cpp" ! -name "main.cpp")
do
  g++ -std=c++17 path/to/files/"$f" -o /path/to/out/....
done
```

Answer (score 1):

We can filter the glob into a Bash array:

```
unset files
for i in ../src/*.cpp
do test "$i" = '../src/main.cpp' || files+=("$i")
done

g++ -std=c++17 "${files[@]}" -o ../out/a.out
```

Or, [using GNU `grep` and `mapfile`](/a/40264051):

```
mapfile -d $'\0' -t files < <(printf '%s\0' ../src/*.cpp | grep -zv '/main\.cpp$')
g++ -std=c++17 "${files[@]}" -o ../out/a.out
```

Comment: That’s more characters than a cmake or make file which would

Answer (score 0):

you can also `ls` all `.cpp` files and pipe that into `grep -v`, to exclude a specific result.

```bash
g++ -std=c++17 `ls *.cpp | grep -v main.cpp` -o a.out
```